# How to add multiple checkbox values with same name using checkbox appearanceStream in PDFBox2

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am looking for adding up 2 or more checkbox values with same name as a single group checkbox values with different export values.

If I try to add multiple checkbox values with the same name causing an issue. First checkbox alone drawing on pdf file. If I change the name then it's loading. How to resolve this issue.

```
for (StructElementDetail element : _pgstrele.getStructElementDetails()) {
            try {
                if ((element.getElementType().startsWith("TB"))) {
                    if (element.getIsFillableFormField()) {

                        List<Integer> _int_bbox_list = convertBBOXtoIntegerList(element.getBBOX());
                        Integer xVal = _int_bbox_list.get(0);
                        Integer yVal = pageHeight - _int_bbox_list.get(1);
                        Integer width = _int_bbox_list.get(2) - _int_bbox_list.get(0);
                        Integer height = _int_bbox_list.get(1) - _int_bbox_list.get(3);
                        String formFieldName = null, toolTip = null, fontSize = null, fontFamily = null;
                        long maxLength = 12;
                        Boolean required = false, multiLine = false, checkSpelling = false, combofChar = false;
                        JSONArray formFieldProperties = (JSONArray) element.getFormFieldProperties();
                        for (Object eleObj : formFieldProperties) {
                            formFieldName = (String) ((JSONObject) eleObj).get("FormFieldName");
                            toolTip = (String) ((JSONObject) eleObj).get("ToolTips");
                            fontSize = (String) ((JSONObject) eleObj).get("FontSize");
                            fontFamily = (String) ((JSONObject) eleObj).get("FontFamily");
                            maxLength = (long) ((JSONObject) eleObj).get("MaxLength");
                            required = (Boolean) ((JSONObject) eleObj).get("Required");
                            multiLine = (Boolean) ((JSONObject) eleObj).get("MultiLine");
                            checkSpelling = (Boolean) ((JSONObject) eleObj).get("CheckSpelling");
                            combofChar = (Boolean) ((JSONObject) eleObj).get("CombofChar");
                        }
                        addTBField(acroForm, page, formFieldName, xVal, yVal, width, height, toolTip, fontSize,
                                fontFamily, maxLength, required, multiLine, checkSpelling, combofChar);
                    }
                } else if ((element.getElementType().startsWith("CB"))) {
                    if (element.getIsFillableFormField()) {

                        List<Integer> _int_bbox_list = convertBBOXtoIntegerList(element.getBBOX());
                        Integer xVal = _int_bbox_list.get(0);
                        Integer yVal = pageHeight - _int_bbox_list.get(1);
                        Integer width = _int_bbox_list.get(2) - _int_bbox_list.get(0);
                        Integer height = _int_bbox_list.get(1) - _int_bbox_list.get(3);
                        String formFieldName = null, toolTip = null, exportValue = null;
                        List<String> exportList = new ArrayList<String>();
                        JSONArray formFieldProperties = (JSONArray) element.getFormFieldProperties();
                        for (Object eleObj : formFieldProperties) {
                            formFieldName = (String) ((JSONObject) eleObj).get("FormFieldName");
                            toolTip = (String) ((JSONObject) eleObj).get("ToolTips");
                            exportValue = (String) ((JSONObject) eleObj).get("ExportValue");
                            exportList.add(exportValue);
                        }
                        addCBField(_pdfDocumentObj, acroForm, page, formFieldName, false, xVal, yVal, width, height,
                                toolTip, exportList);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error in Form Field");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


private static void addCBField(PDDocument document, PDAcroForm acroForm, PDPage page, String name, boolean checked,
        float x, float y, float width, float height, String toolTip, List<String> exportList) {

    try {

        PDRectangle rect = new PDRectangle(x, y, width, height);

        PDCheckBox checkbox = new PDCheckBox(acroForm);
        checkbox.setPartialName(name);
        PDAnnotationWidget widget = checkbox.getWidgets().get(0);
        widget.setPage(page);
        widget.setRectangle(rect);
        widget.setPrinted(true);

        PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary appearanceCharacteristics = new PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary(
                new COSDictionary());

        appearanceCharacteristics.setNormalCaption("4");
        widget.setAppearanceCharacteristics(appearanceCharacteristics);

        /*
         * PDBorderStyleDictionary borderStyleDictionary = new
         * PDBorderStyleDictionary(); borderStyleDictionary.setWidth(1);
         * borderStyleDictionary.setStyle(PDBorderStyleDictionary.STYLE_SOLID);
         * widget.setBorderStyle(borderStyleDictionary);
         */

        PDAppearanceDictionary ap = new PDAppearanceDictionary();
        widget.setAppearance(ap);
        PDAppearanceEntry normalAppearance = ap.getNormalAppearance();

        COSDictionary normalAppearanceDict = (COSDictionary) normalAppearance.getCOSObject();
        normalAppearanceDict.setItem(COSName.Off, createCheckBoxAppearanceStream(document, widget, false));
        normalAppearanceDict.setItem(COSName.YES, createCheckBoxAppearanceStream(document, widget, true));

        
        page.getAnnotations().add(checkbox.getWidgets().get(0));
        acroForm.getFields().add(checkbox);

        checkbox.setAlternateFieldName(toolTip);
        checkbox.setExportValues(exportList);

        if (checked) {
            checkbox.check();
        } else {
            checkbox.unCheck();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private static PDAppearanceStream createCheckBoxAppearanceStream(final PDDocument document,
        PDAnnotationWidget widget, boolean on) throws IOException {
    PDRectangle rect = widget.getRectangle();
    PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary appearanceCharacteristics;
    PDAppearanceStream yesAP = new PDAppearanceStream(document);
    yesAP.setBBox(new PDRectangle(rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight()));
    yesAP.setResources(new PDResources());
    PDPageContentStream yesAPCS = new PDPageContentStream(document, yesAP);
    appearanceCharacteristics = widget.getAppearanceCharacteristics();
    float lineWidth = getLineWidth(widget);
    yesAPCS.setLineWidth(lineWidth); 
    yesAPCS.addRect(0, 0, rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight());
    yesAPCS.addRect(lineWidth / 2, lineWidth / 2, rect.getWidth() - lineWidth, rect.getHeight() - lineWidth);
    if (!on) {
        yesAPCS.close();
        return yesAP;
    }

    yesAPCS.addRect(lineWidth, lineWidth, rect.getWidth() - lineWidth * 2, rect.getHeight() - lineWidth * 2);
    yesAPCS.clip();

    String normalCaption = appearanceCharacteristics.getNormalCaption();
    if (normalCaption == null) {
        normalCaption = "4"; 
    }

    if ("8".equals(normalCaption)) {
        // Adobe paints a cross instead of using the Zapf Dingbats cross symbol
        yesAPCS.setStrokingColor(0f);
        yesAPCS.moveTo(lineWidth * 2, rect.getHeight() - lineWidth * 2);
        yesAPCS.lineTo(rect.getWidth() - lineWidth * 2, lineWidth * 2);
        yesAPCS.moveTo(rect.getWidth() - lineWidth * 2, rect.getHeight() - lineWidth * 2);
        yesAPCS.lineTo(lineWidth * 2, lineWidth * 2);
        yesAPCS.stroke();
    } else {
        // The caption is not unicode, but the Zapf Dingbats code in the PDF
        // Thus convert it back to unicode
        // Assume that only the first character is used.
        String name = PDType1Font.ZAPF_DINGBATS.codeToName(normalCaption.codePointAt(0));
        String unicode = PDType1Font.ZAPF_DINGBATS.getGlyphList().toUnicode(name);
        Rectangle2D bounds = PDType1Font.ZAPF_DINGBATS.getPath(name).getBounds2D();
        float size = (float) Math.min(bounds.getWidth(), bounds.getHeight()) / 1000;
        // assume that checkmark has square size
        // the calculations approximate what Adobe is doing, i.e. put the glyph in the
        // middle
        float fontSize = (rect.getWidth() - lineWidth * 2) / size * 0.6666f;
        float xOffset = (float) (rect.getWidth() - (bounds.getWidth()) / 1000 * fontSize) / 2;
        xOffset -= bounds.getX() / 1000 * fontSize;
        float yOffset = (float) (rect.getHeight() - (bounds.getHeight()) / 1000 * fontSize) / 2;
        yOffset -= bounds.getY() / 1000 * fontSize;
        yesAPCS.beginText();
        yesAPCS.setFont(PDType1Font.ZAPF_DINGBATS, 9);
        yesAPCS.newLineAtOffset(xOffset, yOffset);
        yesAPCS.showText(unicode);
        yesAPCS.endText();
    }
    yesAPCS.close();
    return yesAP;
}

private static float getLineWidth(PDAnnotationWidget widget) {

    PDBorderStyleDictionary bs = widget.getBorderStyle();
    if (bs != null) {
        return bs.getWidth();
    }
    return 1;
}
```

[Sample test data image for the further understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHAkl.png)

Comment: Different fields shouldn't have the same name. I'm not sure I understand the problem, maybe attach the result file that doesn't work and describe what you expected and what happened instead.

Comment: Added the image link of expected and actual behavior outputs. For combo box alone the name should remains same and the export values may vary so that any one of the combo box selected with unique export value

Comment: @Tilman multiple fields, in particular check boxes or radio buttons, may have the same name, and even the same on-value...

Comment: Dears, Any luck on this?

Comment: Each time I read this it's more confusing. Now it's combo boxes? From looking at the image and assuming that gender can be male or female and not both , I think what you really want are radio buttons (which can look like check boxes). There is an example for this but it creates round buttons. You'd have to combine this with the appearance code from the checkbox example.

Comment: Radio button view coming from auto prediction part on Adobe acrobat. I want the name to be set as same for two of the check boxes. Kindly help me out for the particular snippet alone @mkl

Comment: Seyed Ahamed Bilal, maybe you should have a look at the examples pointed out by @Tilman. Tilman, could you provide links to the examples you have in mind?

Comment: https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/branches/2.0/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/interactive/form/CreateRadioButtons.java?view=markup

Comment: I just started reading all this and it is really unclear. So what does the OP want? A radiobutton group with appearances of checkboxes? Or combo boxes? @SeyedAhamedBilal It seems you own *crobat - Can you create a result PDF with shows the behaviour you want?